# “Ich sitze am Tisch” or “zu Tisch”?

Tags: preposition

I was wondering how to translate *I am sitting at the table*, is it *Ich sitze am Tisch* or *Ich sitze zu Tisch*?

Are both possible maybe? Is there a difference between them?

I would have said *am Tisch* but I found this example that proved me wrong:

> Herr Franke ist gerade zu Tisch. In einer Stunde ist er wieder in seinem Büro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct translation of

> "I am sitting at the table."

is

> Ich sitze am Tisch.

---

> Ich sitze zu Tisch.

"zu Tisch" is mostly used with "sein" as a description of a current state or as direction or location.

> Ich bin zu Tisch. Sie ging zu Tisch. Er saß mit zu Tisch.

Today this is more common talking about other people, e.g. when your coworker is having his break and at lunch you might excuse him with

> Er ist zu Tisch.

- Some might use it even when someone just takes a break but without having lunch. Then it just refers to the lunch break of the shift. It does not refer to the time of day, even if it is mostly used at midday.
- Additionally you can excuse someone with being "zu Tisch", if they are currently not seated at a table. It just means they have their break and will eat something during this break.

It was common to say someone is eating ("Er ist am Essen.") in a more polite way. Maybe like their lordships are having dinner. ("Ihre Herrschaften sind zu Tisch.")

Comment: It may be a bit too strict to say the expression can only be combined with _sein_. _Zu Tisch bitten_ at least is also common, and I found this *Spiegel* article from 1951: [Herr Sorge saß mit zu Tisch](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-29194473.html)

Comment: @chirlu. You are right. I edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

> Ich sitze am Tisch

can be used for every table or desk. So it is also posible to use it when you are sitting at your office-desk while writing on your computer, or when sitting on a table-like workbench while repairing a radio. But of course, you can also use it to describe the situation where you sit at a table in a restaurant or at home having lunch or any other meal.

> Ich bin zu Tisch

means that you are having lunch. The original meaning is that you sit on a table while heaving lunch, but when you buy a sandwich and eat it walking through the streets during your lunch-breack, your colleagues might also say that you are »zu Tisch«.

> Ich sitze zu Tisch

is another possibility to say »*Ich bin zu Tisch*«. But since you explicitly use the verb »*sitzen*« (to sit) instead of »*sein*« (to be), it is hard to interpret to eat-a-sandwich-while-walking-scenario into »*er sitzt zu Tisch*«

Answer (score 0):

Zu Tisch sein oder zu Tisch sitzen bedeutet, man ist zum Essen gegangen und sitzt am Mittagstisch.

Comment: Was ist mit Abendessen? Essen im Stehen? Nur auf dem Weg zur Cafeteria etc.  Ausserdem, wenn ich *zu Tisch sitze*, dann *bin ich zu Tisch*. Wenn ich aber *zu Tisch bin*, dann *sitze ich* nicht unbedingt auch *zu Tisch*. Gruß

Comment: @Daniel: Abendessen geht auch, MT war war nur ein Beispiel. Essen im Stehen geht gar nicht, das ist nur ein Imbiss. Auf dem Weg geht.

Comment: Bin ich also für meine Kollegen nicht zu Tisch, wenn ich im Stehen esse? Ich finde Du gibst in Deiner Antwort nur eine Mögliche Bedeutung wieder. Gruss

Comment: Wenn Du zu Tisch bist, Dich aber nicht hinsetzt, ist das Dein Problem. Du brauchst dafür keine Erlaubnis von uns aber erwarte bitte nicht, dass wir uns dafür interessieren, ob Du Dich hinsetzt oder nicht. Du kannst aber Werbeminuten im Umfeld von Länderspielen kaufen, um es jedermann zu kommunizieren.